# cdn jquery in vue is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2

I have a page design (HTML template, CSS, and some jquery on ti) which is pretty legacy and the current task is to make it work with Vue as a first step (we have a plan to override it fully later). Also, it uses Jquery MDB (I know there is a VUE MDB but we plan the move from MDB and it makes no sense to buy the license), so what I want to achieve is to include jquery and MDB to index.html (not like npm dependencies as I just have a local MDB file) and also to have a access to jquery from inside the VUE.

So currently in `index.html`, I'm including dependencies like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= BASE_URL %>vendors/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= BASE_URL %>vendors/mdb/mdb.min.css">


<script src="/vendors/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"> </script>
<script src="/vendors/mdb/mdb.min.js"></script>
```

but when I'm trying to use jquery in VUE for example like this `$('.datepicker').pickadate({...` I'm getting the error `‘$’ is not defined`

What should I do to make external jquery work in/with VUE?

**UPDATED**

What I did, now I have iin the `index.html` like this:

```
<script src="/vendors/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"> </script>
<script src="/vendors/mdb/mdb.min.js"></script>
```

and as an addition, I also install npm jquery package and including it to the file which needs it like this: `import $ from 'jquery'` . Now I'm getting different error, `B(...)(...).pickadate is not a function` and I'm not user what is this `B(...)(...)` as in code I have `$('.datepicker').pickadate({...`

Probably it's some conflict as now I have 2 jquery in the page...

Comment: I would install jQuery from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery), then import it wherever you need it

Comment: Also you could try downloading those two files, placing them somewhere convenient and import or require them in your JS code.

Comment: Not sure if this would work for you, but there's a [mdb npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)

Comment: if I use jquery npm package and adding both jqeury and mdb file to the main.js, like this `import  'jquery'
import './assets/vendors/mdb/mdb.min'` I'm getting error from mdb than jquery is not defined I also tried `import $ from 'jquery'` and import jQuery from 'jquery'  the same issue

Comment: I know there is the MDB npm package but MDB is not free and we plan to get rid of it later. So it makes no sense to pay for a license (this file was included as a part of the design so we got it for free). And the link you sent is to MongoDB not to MDB

Comment: Okay, but I see on their website that there's a free version of MDB. I tested loading both jQuery and the free version of MDB on a sample vue app and I can access jQuery from App.vue, and there are no errors. Can you use the free version since you're going to get rid of it anyways, or do you have to use the one you have currently? [Here](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/getting-started/download/) is the download link of the free one (I downloaded the .zip). Also if you are importing jQuery in main.js AND the CDN then try importing it like this: `import jq from 'jquery'`. I'm thinking that

Comment: conflicting `'$'` could be the problem, so if you import it with an alias other than `'$'`, maybe it will work.

Comment: the free version is not working in the current situation, this script I have is a pro version. I tried to use `jQuery` instead of `$` and not working. Also not sure if you saw, I update the question with more info

Comment: I see. I can't seem to be able to reproduce the problem with the free version, and I can't think of a solution of the top of my head. If you share the (MDB) files you used I can try and reproduce the problem so I can look for a solution, but if not, I probably can't be of much help to you.